# form validation before i do a onclick for instert in db

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have doubts about if I can make a validation of a form before a onlick function that sends data to insert in a db, because when i do click the data it is sent altough the form is not complete.

HTML

```
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control input" required="required" name="nomoc" id="nomoc"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control input" required="required" name="qtyoc" id="qtyoc"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control input" required="required" name="skuoc" id="skuoc"></td>
<td>
    <select class="form-control m-b" id="provoc" required="" value="">
        <?php while($dato2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $dato2['ID_prov'];?>"><?php echo $dato2['nom_fantasia'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control input" required="required" name="link" id="link"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control input" required="required" name="vtoc" id="vtoc"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control input" required="required" name="vdoc" id="vdoc"></td>
```

JS

```
function addoc{
    var name = document.getElementById("nomoc").value;
    var qty = document.getElementById("qtyoc").value;
    var sku = document.getElementById("skuoc").value;
    var prov = document.getElementById("provoc").value;
    var link = document.getElementById("link").value;
    var vt = document.getElementById("vtoc").value;
    var vd = document.getElementById("vdoc").value;
    var obs = document.getElementById("obsoc").value;
    $.get("funciones.php", {
        function : 34,
        name : name,
        qty : qty,
        sku : sku,
        prov : prov,
        link : link,
        vt : vt,
        vd :vd,
        obs : obs
    }, function(data){});
};
```

Comment: `required` parameters on input fields only work when using and submitting a form. You are using ajax, this is why these parameters will not work. You will have to validate the input using javascript. Also, you should always check the data on the server side as well and not just dump the data in your database.

Comment: An important side note, I also hope you have a validation server side as well!?

Comment: i dont have a validation from the server side :(

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the if else part and add your jQuery validation to that.

```
function addoc{
        var name = document.getElementById("nomoc").value;
        var qty = document.getElementById("qtyoc").value;
        var sku = document.getElementById("skuoc").value;
        var prov = document.getElementById("provoc").value;
        var link = document.getElementById("link").value;
        var vt = document.getElementById("vtoc").value;
        var vd = document.getElementById("vdoc").value;
        var obs = document.getElementById("obsoc").value;
        if(custome_Jquery_validation)
        {
        //validation error
        }
        else if(another_custome_Jquery_validation)
        {
          //validation error
        }.....
        else{
          $.get("funciones.php", {function : 34,  name : name, qty : qty, sku : sku, prov : prov, link : link, vt : vt, vd :vd, obs : obs}, function(data){
        });
        }
        };
```